# Render plots in RMarkdown with the same dimensions as RStudio Viewer

Tags: plot, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

When I visualize plots in the RStudio plot viewer, plot dimensions are usually distorted if I select the Zoom Plot option.
When I knitter an RMarkdown document coded plots are displayed in the dimensions of the unzoomed viewer, therefore plots I coded with the zoomed version in mind, I get illegible results. Any option to render the plots in the same dimensions as the Zoom Viewer?
[RStudio Zoom Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acPIa.jpg)[RMardkdown rendered version of the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz6N1.jpg)

Comment: You have complete control over the size in R Markdown using the `fig.width` and `fig.height` chunk options (which can be set to different defaults if you want the same dims throughout your document).  I don't know the rules for the RStudio Zoom, but it shouldn't take long to work out width and height values that match it.

Comment: thanks. Indeed a width of 12 and height of 7 seems to be equivalent to RStudio Zoom tool